# Использование одинаковых спрайтов несколько раз

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

У меня два человечка, которые совершенно одинаковые, но имеют разные координаты. Мне хотелось бы как-нибудь оптимизировать свой код, потому что создавать два изображения, а потом два хэша, не вариант, как по мне. Я пробовала задавать координаты в качестве аргументов функции tickMonster, но почему-то так вообще работать не хочет, а оборачивать весь код в функцию не вариант, потому что координаты человечка мне ещё нужны будут в другом месте.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('block1');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let sxM = 0,
        syM = 0,
        tickCountM = 0;

    let redMonster1 = new Image();
    redMonster1.src = 'https://cdn.freelance.ru/img/portfolio/pics/00/33/9B/3382151.jpg?mt=25604025';
    let redMonster2 = new Image();
    redMonster2.src = 'https://cdn.freelance.ru/img/portfolio/pics/00/33/9B/3382151.jpg?mt=25604025';

    let redM1 = {
        name: 'redWhale',
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        blockW: 428,
        blockX: 100,
        blockY: 100,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        speed: 2.4,
        score: 100,
        redMonster: redMonster1,
    };


    let redM2 = {
        name: 'redWhale',
        x: 100,
        y: 200,
        blockW: 428,
        blockX: 100,
        blockY: 200,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        speed: 3,
        score: 100,
        redMonster: redMonster2,
    };

    let monsters = [];
    monsters.push(Object.create(redM1));
    monsters.push(Object.create(redM2));
    requestAnimationFrame(tickMonster);
    console.log(monsters.length);

    function tickMonster() {
        for (let i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++) {
            let mArmy = monsters[i];
            if (tickCountM > 10) {
                ctx.clearRect(mArmy.blockX, mArmy.blockY, 428, mArmy.height);
                sxM = (sxM === 500 ? 0 : sxM + 100);
                ctx.drawImage(mArmy.redMonster, sxM, syM, mArmy.width, mArmy.height, mArmy.x, mArmy.y, mArmy.width, mArmy.height);
                tickCountM = 0;
            }
            mArmy.x += mArmy.speed;
            if (mArmy.x > mArmy.blockX + mArmy.blockW - mArmy.width) {
                mArmy.speed = -mArmy.speed;
                mArmy.x = mArmy.blockX + mArmy.blockW - mArmy.width;
            }
            if (mArmy.x < mArmy.blockX) {
                mArmy.speed = -mArmy.speed;
                mArmy.x = mArmy.blockX;
            }
            tickCountM += 1;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(tickMonster);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="block1" width="600" height="300" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать одно изображение вообще не проблема. Я убрал второе изображение и для обоих спрайтов загружается только одна картинка.

Дальше, я не вижу никакого смысла в создании двух одинаковых объектов за исключением нескольких полей. Можно создать один общий объект и добавляя его в массив изменять по заданным свойствам. И это не только улучшит код. Теперь вам будет намного легче добавлять новый объект.

Вот код(чтобы показать, что он работает, я добавил еще одного монстра):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('block1');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let sxM = 0,
        syM = 0,
        tickCountM = 0;

    let redMonster = new Image();
    redMonster.src = 'https://cdn.freelance.ru/img/portfolio/pics/00/33/9B/3382151.jpg?mt=25604025';


    //свойства монстров
    let coorX = [100, 100, 200];
    let coorY = [100, 200, 300];
    let speed = [2.4, 3, 4];
    let blockY = [100, 200, 300];
    //свойства монстров
    
    
    //объект
    let redM = {
        name: 'redWhale',
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        blockW: 428,
        blockX: 100,
        blockY: 100,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        speed: 2.4,
        score: 100,
        redMonster: redMonster,
    };


    let monsters = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // цикл чтобы добавить трех монстров
      monsters.push(Object.create(redM)); // добавляем монстра в массив
      monsters[i].x = coorX[i]; // изменяем координаты x
      monsters[i].y = coorY[i]; // изменяем координаты y
      monsters[i].speed = speed[i]; // изменяем скорость
      monsters[i].blockY = blockY[i]; // изменяем блок
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(tickMonster);
    console.log(monsters.length);

    function tickMonster() {
        for (let i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++) {
            let mArmy = monsters[i];
            if (tickCountM > 10) {
                ctx.clearRect(mArmy.blockX, mArmy.blockY, 428, mArmy.height);
                sxM = (sxM === 500 ? 0 : sxM + 100);
                ctx.drawImage(mArmy.redMonster, sxM, syM, mArmy.width, mArmy.height, mArmy.x, mArmy.y, mArmy.width, mArmy.height);
                tickCountM = 0;
            }
            mArmy.x += mArmy.speed;
            if (mArmy.x > mArmy.blockX + mArmy.blockW - mArmy.width) {
                mArmy.speed = -mArmy.speed;
                mArmy.x = mArmy.blockX + mArmy.blockW - mArmy.width;
            }
            if (mArmy.x < mArmy.blockX) {
                mArmy.speed = -mArmy.speed;
                mArmy.x = mArmy.blockX;
            }
            tickCountM += 1;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(tickMonster);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="block1" width="600" height="500" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
```

*P.S.* Я так и не понял, почему они называются монстры :D